# Unfamiliar .exe files attempt to run repeatedly

Tags: windows-vista, virus, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

User Account Control recently alerted me that a program named `setupxxxxxxxxx.exe` (the `x`'s being seemingly random numbers) was trying to run. When I said no, another file with different numbers tried to run. This continued to happen over and over.

I traced the files back to `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp`. There, I found 10 `setupxxxxxxxxx.exe` files and ten application manifests. The .exe files are all 16KB and the manifests are all 1KB.

What's going on? Should I delete all of these?

Comment: Did you try using any anti-virus or anti-malware apps?

Comment: [See my post over here to disinfect your PC.][1]


.


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533

Comment: About as trivial as the Virus Total answer.

Answer (score 2):

Upload them to [VirusTotal](http://www.virustotal.com/), and if they report back positive, start backing up your system and get ready to nuke it.

If it doesn't, you're going to want to look in further.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly likely this are virus or malware installers.

You should make sure your antivirus software is up to date and functioning properly, and then you should have it perform a full system scan. (You do have Antivirus software running, right?)

Then you should delete these files anyways, even if the antivirus says their OK. Setup programs should not be running unless you have allowed them to or instructed them to. Allowed, as in the case of a windows update process. Instructed, as in the case of your installing an application on purpose. Any other situation, even if the software is legitimate, is suspect and should therefore be prevented.